# Is posible play two mp3 files with xamarin media manager at same time

Tags: forms, xamarin, plugins, media

How to play two mp3 files in xamarin forms with xamarin mediamanager plugin at same time?

```
public IPlaybackController PlaybackController => 
CrossMediaManager.Current.PlaybackController;
```

Is is possible to duplicate CrossMediamanager?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Cross-fading between two mp3s start/end, syncing of two mp3 playback? etc..

Comment: I want to play two mp3 at same time and control volume separately. I use xamarinmediamanager. Is posible two files with this nugget ? If is not posible, any other ?

Comment: Depending upon the accuracy of the playback timeline, on iOS you can use AudioQueues to absolutely control the sync, otherwise you can create multiple AVAudioPlayers instances and start `Play` on them at the same time. On Android, you can have multiple MediaPlayers, but depending upon API and device, both might not play at the same time, but multiple AudioTracks can be streamed within separate threads. If you need absolute control over the sync, mixing the two streams in a single AudioTracks is one way to go.

Comment: and how do you do with mediamanager nuget? Any sample ? My first audio i voice and my second is music. I want t control volumen separetly